# How to access a device connected to a different computer using the IP Address

Tags: linux, networking, firefox, ssh-tunnel

- I have a device connected via ethernet cable to one computer (PC-1).
- I know the IP Address of the device.
- I know the IP Address of the computer (PC-1) also and I can `ssh` into that computer (PC-1) from my computer (PC-2) without a problem.
- The problem is, the Firefox version on that computer (PC-1) is too old, to configure the device.
- How can I access from my firefox on (PC-2), the device connected to that other computer (PC-1)?
- And this computer (PC-2) does not have the correct cabling that would allow me to connect the device directly to it.

```
Firefox on PC-2 ----> PC-1 (IP known) ----> device (IP known)
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If I knew what to try, I would've tried it already. _"What have you tried so far?"_ is an oft repeated comment on SO. I understand the frustration of contributors when being overburdened by school-assignment posts. But sometimes you don't know even where to start. So yes, @DougDeden, I've tried till now nothing. And this is my first shot in dark to see what comes up.

Comment: Can you ping Device from PC-2? Have you tried entering the IP address of Device into Firefox on PC-2? Have you tried updating Firefox on PC-1?

Comment: Why can't you update Firefox on PC1, or install another browser?

Comment: @DougDeden, I cannot ping device from PC-2. How should it even understand the IP address of that? I did try entering the IP address of the device into firefox on PC-2 and it gave up after a certain time. I cannot update the Firefox. I am not the administrator on PC-1.

Comment: Actually, thank you all guys for taking the time out to reply and comment. I found for the moment an easier solution. I connected my PC-2 to the hub that was present between the device and PC-1. (The hub is though physically not easy to access/visible). I can now directly communicate with the device from PC-2 without needing PC-1 as an intermediary.  Thank you all. I will try your solutions tomorrow morning also and let you know what worked (in case one day, I cannot access this hub). Thanks again.

Comment: I guess, I understand now. The term I should've been "googling" for, is "SSH tunneling" probably, instead of the long-winding text I was searching for as in the title of this question. Added the tag to the question for others who might stumble along a similar path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is to connect to the device via an SSH tunnel trough PC-1. So, on PC-2, you can make the tunnel with :

```
# SSH -L <inPort>:<deviceIP>:<outPort> <userPC-1>@<IP-PC-1>
```

with :

- inPort : a random free port on PC-2 (80 or 8080 for example)
- deviceIp : IP address of the device, this address need to be reachable by PC-1
- outPort : The port to connect to the device (80 i guess)
- userPC-1 : A user on PC-1 to connect via SSH (the one you used)
- IP-PC-1 : IP address of PC-1n this address need to be reachable by PC-2

After you established this tunnel, you will be able to connect to the device on PC-2 wia the URL

```
http://localhost:<inPort>/
```

for example, if the service you want to contact on device is on port 80 and have the address of 192.168.1.10, PC-1 have address of 192.168.2.10 (PC-2 network) and 192.168.1.11 (Device network) and can be accessed with the login marcus. You can enter the following command on PC-2

```
# SSH -L 8080:192.168.1.10:80 marcus@192.168.2.10
```

and access the service by entering the following URL on PC-2
    http://localhost:80

Answer (score 1):

You want to use SSH and port forwarding

Computer 1- old machine w/ device attached
Computer 2 - your desktop etc

```
ssh -L9090:ip.of.device:port_device_listens_on user@computer1
```

So if the Device is at 10.0.2.15 and listening on port 7000 it would bea

```
ssh -L9090:10.0.2.15:7000 user@computer1
```

Log in and authenticate, then simply open a browser on your local machine and go to http://localhost:9090

Comment: +1 upvote. Thanks for the answer.